# Scope function only called once, then looses binding

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, binding, angularjs-scope

I have an AngularJS site with a jQueryUI sortable on my page. I've created a `directive` to instantiate the sortable functionality from an attribute, like so:

```
<ul sortable>
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>BBB</li>
  <li>CCC</li>
</ul>
```

The jQueryUI sortable comes witha set of `events`. I want it to call my custom function when the `stop` event is triggered. So I'm doing that like this:

```
<ul sortable="{stop: test() }">
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>BBB</li>
  <li>CCC</li>
</ul>
```

My directive initialize the `sortable` plugin with the settings I supply in the attribute. The `test()` function (which is in my `$scope`) is called once, but then seems to lose its binding.

Here's an example plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/rTAuMMZXREPNHWmgLGtV?p=preview

---

If you go the my `directive` and uncomment the code where it says ***add anon func***, then you'll see that I can only make it work when I hard code my `$scope` function in an anonymous function that way.

But I'd like to specify what `$scope` function it should call from the HTML `attribute`.

Is there a way to make this work the way I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by passing in the object as a reference:

```
myApp.directive('sortable', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      sortable: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {
      if ($.fn.sortable) {
        el.sortable(scope.sortable);
      }
    }
  };
}]);
```

This way you could pass the functions by name:

```
<ul sortable="{stop: test}">
  <li>AAA</li>
  <li>BBB</li>
  <li>CCC</li>
</ul>
```

See the [working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/D0pZLlaMJeQO4PLtI8ti?p=preview)